# PHP class not working " OOP "

Tags: php, class

here's my include.php:

```
<?php
class cars {
    protected $_car;

    public function __costruct($carName) {
        $this->_car = $carName;

    }

    public function getcarname (){
        return $this->_car;
    }
}?>
```

and here's my index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'include.php';

$selling = new cars('Ford');
echo $selling->getcarname();
?>
```

Still echo's nothing! you can say I'm new to classes but I know php, it's kinda' complicated to deal with it, and I find it makes no since and waste of code, anyway still I want to learn it, so whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Off-topic, but your naming convention is pretty bad. You should use CamelCase for classes and camelCase for functions, i.e. rename your class to `Cars` and your function to `getCarName`. And it doesn't make much sense that your class is called `Cars` when it only represents a single car.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo, the constructor function is called `__construct`, not `__costruct`.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used OOP but would

```
$selling = new cars;
```

work?

Comment: No, because there's no default value for $carName in the constructor method (or at least what should be the constructor), so it would complain if it wasn't given a value

Answer (score 0):

Typo in construct. It says costruct